# Gap between fork and frame

Tags: frames, fork

I removed the fork from my old racer because I was hit by a car. When I'm trying to put the new fork on the frame, I get a gap where the top bearing is situated. What should I do? Could I just remove the bearing and put everything in place, or is that just too stupid?

Comment: Do not remove the bearing. It sounds like the steer tube on your new fork is too long for your head tube. Post back with a picture if possible and we should be able to clear up the problem.

Comment: I can't upload pictures, but I found this one. It's the same frame:

Comment: I can't upload pictures, but I found this one. It's the same frame: http://cdn.velospace.org/files/peugeota.jpg This one is threaded, but when I put the unthreaded fork, I get a gap between the frame and the silver "screw"ring under the stem. Maybe I should ask this different. Do I need to do something with the head bearing when I go from threaded to unthreaded fork and stem?

Comment: Threadless forks usually have a lip at the crown for the lowest race to be pressed on.  I don't know if threaded forks have this.  If they are not supposed to have the lip, it may be causing the problem?

Comment: You're trying to change from a threaded fork and stem to an unthreaded fork and stem? If that's the case, you need a whole different headset - the "head bearing" as you called it.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I need to change the headset. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your head tube was ovalized when the wreck occured causing a gap. Also keep in mind that head tubes come in many sizes. Your fork may be the wrong size.

See this Wikipedia article for more:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headset_(bicycle_part)

Comment: If this helps, if you see this picture: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Bicycle_headset_exploded_view-en.png I've got the gap between the upper head tube race and the adjustable race ( And just thing it's unthreaded )